# display selective fields in splunk in query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula, splunk-sum

I am trying to create a table in splunk of some service endpoint and calculation time taken by each endpoint, now the problem i want to display selected endpoints based on time. This is the query i wrote to display the fields.

```
<query>index="test" | eval report=case(match(uri_path, "api/abc/"), 
"anc", match(uri_path, "api/bcd/**"), "bcd", match(uri_path, "efc"), 
"efc") | eval ms=round(microseconds/1000) | stats count, mean(ms) as 
avgMillis, min(ms), max(ms), perc75(ms), perc95(ms), perc99(ms), 
stdev(ms) by report | eval avgMillis=round(avgMillis) | eval 
stdev(ms)=round('stdev(ms)') </query>
```

How should only end points be displayed only if they are more than 1 secs.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the query:

```
| search avgMillis>1
```